# How to extract value from an Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js

I am querying my db in node and have got the result in the form of an object like this - **[ [1234] ]**.

I want to extract this value and convert it into a string and then pass it onto the client side. I have written the other required code but I am not able to get value from this object. Can anyone help me in getting the value and converting it to string?

Comment: please post the code you have do with it.

Comment: it's an array of a single array

Comment: Objects in javascript are denoted by `{}`, what you have is an array `[]`. And it's only element is another array, that again has only one element, a number. so whatever variable you put the result in, let's say `foo`. You'd just do `foo[0][0]` and you are done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since, the result you've got is a [two-dimensional array](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/tutorial/two_dimensional_arrays.cfm), you can get the value and convert it into a string *(using [toString()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_number.asp) method)* in the following way ...

```js
var result = [ [1234] ];
var string;
result.forEach(function(e) {
  string = e.toString();
});
console.log(string);
```

** *this solution will also work if you have multiple results, ie. `[ [1234], [5678] ]`*

Answer (score 2):

You have a nested array, meaning that you have an array inside another array:

```
   [ [1234] ]
// ^-^====^-^
```

To get the first value of the parent array, use the square brackets: `[0]`. **Remember that indexes start at `0`!**

If you have `val = [[1234]]`, `val[0]` gets the enclosed array: `[1234]`. Then, `1234` is a value in *that* array (the first value), so you use the square brackets again to get it: `val[0][0]`.

To convert to string, you can use `+ ""` which forces the number to become a string, or the `toString()` method.

```js
var val = [[1234]];
var str = val[0][0] + "";
//     or val[0][0].toString();

console.log(str, typeof str);
```

You can read more about arrays [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp).

Answer (score 1):

```js
var response = [ [1234] ];
console.log(response[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

to extract values from a string array or an array we can use **.toString()**

> Ex:

```
let names = ["peter","joe","harry"];
let fname = names.toString();
 output = peter ,joe,harry
```

or

```
 let name:string[] = this.customerContacts.map(
 res => res.firstname 
 let fname =name.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using De-structuring Array concept:**

```
const arr = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]];
const [[p, q, r, s, t]] = arr;
console.log(p, q, r, s, t);
```

**Output:** 1 2 3 4 5